# VirtualBox crashes on a macOS host when attempting to shutdown Ubuntu guest OS

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running a guest Ubuntu 18 on VirtualBox 5.2.20 on a host macOS Mojave on a MacBook Air.

I installed everything using the default settings, and most of it works fine. However, when I attempt to shutdown the guest, the guest window disappears, as expected (it appears from all signs that the shutdown process succeeded), but about 2 seconds later the entire VirtualBox program crashes, and my macOS host displays an error message saying:>

> VirtualBox quit unexpectedly

The macOS crash logs say something about `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` and `Segmentation fault: 11`.

This happens for two different ways I shutdown:

1. select "power off" from within the Ubuntu guest UI
2. select ACPI shutdown from the VirtualBox menu

I remember having this exact problem in earlier versions of VirtualBox and macos also.

Is this a bug with VirtualBox or am I doing something wrong?